# Can't increase base memory on Virtualbox

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I'm running Virtualbox to run my server on CentOS

The thing is I have memory available on my Xserver 16 GB

[image]

And the max I can up is only up to 4GB

[image]

I don't know why I can't give it more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a mac user, but are you booting up the host with the 64bit kernel? Is the program using the 64bit version?

Generally, a 4GB limit is an indication of a 32bit/64bit issue.

I found this article on VirtualBox's site with a user that is having the a similar issue. It may help you resolve your problem.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=49071&p=223136&hilit=RAM+Limit#p223136